# Netlogo - why is "if" statement ignored?

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to Netlogo and trying to simulate (a part of) a brain network in which the turtles represent brain areas and 'fclinks' represent the links between those brain areas, which should decrease in weight ('weight-edge') over time.

This is a snippet of code:

```
ask fclinks
[ set weight-edge weight-edge - fc-change ]
; change thickness of links
ask fclinks
[ if weight-edge < 1000
  [ set shape "medium"
  ]
  if weight-edge < 500
  [ set shape "thin"
    ask symptom 3
    [ set color 15 ]
  ]
]
end
```

'symptom 3' is another node that should change color if the weight-edge passes a certain threshold (when weight edge is lower than 500). However, the node is already changing color before this threshold is reached.

Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have the node changing colour if the weight is low `if weight-edge < 500` but your question is phrased in such a way that I think you don't want it to change colour until the threshold is reached, so the colour indicate higher weights. If this is the correct interpretation, then the problem is simply that you have < instead of >

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! Sorry for the unclear question. What I meant is I want the color to change when weight-edge is lower than 500.

Comment: the code looks reasonable - have you done basic debugging like inspecting one of the links that changes colour too soon and see whether the weight-edge values seem reasonable? You could have a monitor on your interface that reports `min [weight-edge] of fclinks` to see when the colour change should happen

Comment: Thank you, the monitor was very helpful! I figured out that there were some links present that were < 500 from the beginning. That's why the color change happened too early. I changed it by creating a new if statement for only the link that starts > 500. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I'd suggest using the (ifelse cond1 [ act1] cond 2 [ act 2] ... else [ act-n] ) structure to guaranteed you've specified exactly one choice as well as everything else that might happen.  You ask if weight-edge < 1000, and do something, then don't exit and immediately ask if weight-edge < 500 and do something else.  Both could be true - what then? Which one should rule? etc. What if you flip the order and first test for < 500 and then if that fails test for < 1000? etc.